# Add map created from other to my website google earth engine?

Tags: javascript, apigee, google-earth-engine, google-earth-plugin

I want to add [this](https://leolaipelt.users.earthengine.app/view/manchahandiphana) map to my website. Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make a free account with [datapane](https://datapane.com) and use [the geemap package](https://geemap.org/) which has functions for turning a GEE layer into an interactive datapane object, which can then be imbedded in HTML.

See [this tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/giswqs/geemap/blob/master/examples/notebooks/24_publish_maps.ipynb) on using geemap to make an interactive datapane object.

Once the map has been created, the map widget will be in your datapane account along with a code snippet for embedding in HTML!

I noticed that the link you sent is using GEE in the JavaScript environment, so this answer would require you to engage with the Python API, however I have personally hosted interactive maps this way and it is fairly simple. One caveat is that the maps will need to be re-updated every few days when the token expires.